# замена каждого первого вхождения определенного элемента во всех id определенного стовця mySQL / php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Такая вот проблем нужно изменить (как пример) все подстрочки *Google* строки *Google is the best Google * из колонки descriptions в бд, но только первое вхождение.
Делал что-то такого типа - но потом понял что LIMIT не работает в Update...

```
        $sql1=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `" . $_POST['table'] . "` WHERE `" .$_POST['Column'] . "` LIKE '%" . $string . "%'");
    if (mysqli_fetch_array($sql1) > 0){
        $sql_select_like=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);
        $y=array_keys($sql_select_like);
        while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){
            $sql_replace__method = "UPDATE `" . $_POST['table'] . "` SET `". $_POST['column'] ."` = REPLACE(" . $_POST['column'] . ", '" . $string . "', '" . $_POST['NewString'] . "')
            WHERE `" . $id . "` = ". 2 ." LIMIT 1";
            $sql_replace__query = mysqli_query($connection,$sql_replace__method);
            echo 'Изминения в ряде id: ' . $id . '(' . $id_name . ')' . ', в столбце: ' . $_POST['column'] . '  Значения ' . $string . ' на: ' . $_POST['NewString'] . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы и так все это делаете на стороне PHP, так и пользуйтесь PHP
И честно говоря, вообще не понятно что ваш код делает, рискну адаптировать его:

```
$table = $_POST['table'];
$column = $_POST['column'];
$string = $_POST['string'];
$newstring = $_POST['newstring'];

$sql = "SELECT id,$column FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE `" . $column . "` LIKE '%" . $string . "%'";
if ($result == mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $newvalue = str_replace($string, $newstring, $res[$column], 1);
        mysqli_query($connection, "update $table set $column = '".$newvalue."' where id = ".$res['id']);
    }
}
```